# WCF service optimal configuration

Tags: wcf, binding, configuration

I am using basicHttpBinding for my wcf service

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_UtilityService" 
          closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="01:00:00" 
          receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00" 
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
          maxBufferSize="52428800" maxBufferPoolSize="52428800" 
          maxReceivedMessageSize="52428800" 
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" 
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas 
             maxDepth="52428800" maxStringContentLength="52428800" 
             maxArrayLength="52428800" maxBytesPerRead="52428800" 
             maxNameTableCharCount="52428800"/>
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>

<behavior name="httpMetadataBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="52428800" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="200" maxConcurrentSessions="200" maxConcurrentInstances="200" />
</behavior>
```

Please let know what values I should put for `maxArrayLength`, `maxItemsInObjectGraph`, open/close and receive timeouts. If I set this to max allowed values, is there any harm in doing that?

How size and timeout values should be defined optimally?

Answer (score 0):

*Optimally* always **heavily depends** on what exactly it is you're doing and what your requirements are.

There's not **ONE optimal** setting -- don't you think the WCF team would have made that the default setting, if it existed?

Also:

**YES** setting everything max allowable size **opens the door** for potential denial-of-service attacks - that's the reason it's **NOT** set to 2 GB for each of those size values in the first place!